# Entropy in a real engine and in a refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I've been studying thermodynamics recently but I get confused on calculating the entropy of a real engine as well as in a refrigerator. Can you please tell me how to calculate  it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general the entropy will depend on what the engine/refrigerator is made out of, and changes in entropy of a total system will depend on what process the engine is going through${}^{1}$.  In general, for any process that generates heat in a sequence of small amounts $(\delta Q)_{i}$, the total entropy generated will be:

$$\Delta S = \sum_{i}\frac{(\Delta Q)_{i}}{T}$$

Generically, this heat will be transferred to the environment, which will obey the same equation with a different temperature.  To get any further, we will need some sort of equation that tells us how the heat exchanged depends on the temperature.  This will depend on the exact process the engine/refrigerator is using.

${}^{1}$Note: entropy is a state function, so "the entropy of the engine" will not change over a cycle -- the engine will increase, perhaps, the entropy of the universe